# how to detect that Windows finished adding/removing storage devices (not as drive letters, only as devices)

Tags: windows, delphi, storage, device

I have some computers with a simplified Windows in which storage devices that are added/removed don't get automatically drive letters.
So I have to find a way to detect that are added/removed.
One way (that I know) is with WM_DEVICECHANGE message.
On those computers the message is sent to windows only with WParam 7 and LParam 0.
So I could run my detection code when this message is received by my application.
The problem is that it takes some time for the device to be completely recognized; meantime my application is "bombarded" with a "salvo" of WM_DEVICECHANGE messages and the detection code is started even 6..7 times.
To solve I could add a timer who is reinitialized by a new message; if, after some time (1..2 sec), the application is not receiving the message, the detection code is started.
But I don't like this approach 100% because it doesn't take into consideration other factors as: the speed of the computer, other programs that slow down Windows, different storage device types etc. And the fact that the detection code finishes after a delay it's a little annoying.

Does anybody know a more professional solution...?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I haven't done anything similar yet, however look at shell events, with shell you can also be notified(only once/action) when a file is being removed, changed, modified, etc. I'm sure that you can find something useful on msdn and then ask people to convert the code to Delphi if you're not familiar with the syntax(VC) or the equivalent from C# to Delphi.

Comment: @Dorin, Ok, I know I can look and search but I already did that and got nothing and I came here for help...

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with this these messages yesterday and in my testprogram I get only one message for adding and one for removal if I filter the messages.

See my [blog](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/01/14/convert-drive-bitmask-to-drive-letter/) for a more detailed description.

Comment: I looked at your blog. The problem in my case is that in the messages (WParam) I don't have DEV_BROADCAST_HDR structure, only number "7". Is there any other way to filter this messages...?

Comment: @John Mirror: they are defined in the Jedi Apilib http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/jedi-api-headers/

Answer (score 0):

It's true, for most cases you get numerous messages. My solution to this was similar to yours, except that instead of the timer I used a thread. My waiting time was 15s in this case (after DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL).

In fact DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL is exactly the one you're looking for when I look at the wording of your question. The *device* is available at that time, even if more notifications follow. I get the following when plugging in a USB key:

- DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
- DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
- DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
- DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL (DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME, drive letter has been made available)
- DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
- DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
- DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED

For your purpose the DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED notifications are irrelevant. You are interested solely in DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL ($8000 in Delphi parlance).

Besides, it would really help if you would refer to the messages by their symbolic name, not their number.